# visual studio mac, locals is empty when running code

Tags: macos, visual-studio, visual-studio-debugging, visual-studio-mac

I am using visual studio mac and am having trouble setting it up, I have opened the locals debugging pad but whenever I run my code the locals pad remains blank, I'm trying to view my lists and arrays.
Does anyone know this is happening and what the solution is?

Comment: The locals window will only show variables when the app is at a break point.

Comment: Right okay cheers

Comment: @Rhys Hudspeth, Do you resolve this issue now? If it has been resolved, would you please share your solution as an answer? So it could help other community members directly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to be stepping through the debugger in order to see the variables in the local window per msdn:

> The Locals window displays variables that are defined in the local
>   scope, which is generally the function or method that is currently
>   being executed.

Ref: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bhawk8xd.aspx